# Porting java code to Python

Tags: java, python

I want port some java code to Python, but I can't get functions that replace these java methods:

```
 ChannelBuffer buf

 buf.skipBytes(1);
 buf.readUnsignedInt();
 buf.readUnsignedByte();
 buf.readUnsignedShort();
 buf.readLong();
```

Please can somebody help me with this?, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably use the `struct` module for this; specifically, [`struct.unpack_from`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack_from). The equivalent to those five method calls would be:

```
struct.unpack_from('x', buf)
struct.unpack_from('I', buf)
struct.unpack_from('B', buf)
struct.unpack_from('H', buf)
struct.unpack_from('l', buf)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the Python `struct` module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html